# Disable a checkbox created at runtime

Tags: asp.net-2.0

In my asp.net application i have created checkboxes at runtime. I want to disable the checked checkbox when i click on a button. How do I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        tr = new TableRow();
        tr.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Groove;
        for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++)
        {
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Groove;
            ch = new CheckBox();
            tc.Controls.Add(ch);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        form1.Controls.Add(ch);
        mRoleCheckBoxList.Add("RoleName", ch);
    }
}




protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    IDictionaryEnumerator RoleCheckBoxEnumerator = mRoleCheckBoxList.GetEnumerator();
    while (RoleCheckBoxEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        CheckBox RoleCheckBox = (CheckBox)RoleCheckBoxEnumerator.Value;
        string BoxRoleName = (string)RoleCheckBox.Text;
        if (RoleCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            RoleCheckBox.Enabled = false;
            break;
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One rule-of-thumb while dealing with dynamically generated user controls is that you have to add them to the container on **EVERY POSTBACK**.

Just modify your code to generate the controls on every postback, and your code will start working like a ***charm***!

### EDIT

I am unsure what the `ch` variable is. I have assumed that its a checkbox. If I am correct, then all you have to do is to modify these lines

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    form1.Controls.Add(ch);
    mRoleCheckBoxList.Add("RoleName", ch);
}
```

to this

```
//if(!IsPostBack)
{
    form1.Controls.Add(ch);
    mRoleCheckBoxList.Add("RoleName", ch);
}
```

### EDIT 2

This is the code for generating 10 checkboxes dynamically -

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox c = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        c = new CheckBox();
        c.ID = "chk" + i.ToString();
        c.Text = "Checkbox " + (i + 1).ToString();

        container.Controls.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Check the checkboxes when the page renders on the client side, click the button. This will cause a postback and the checkboxes will be generated again. In the click event of the button, you'll be able to find the checkboxes like this -

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox c = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        c = container.FindControl("chk" + i.ToString()) as CheckBox;
        //Perform your relevant checks here, and disable the checkbox.
    }
}
```

I hope this is clear.

Comment: sir 
i have done the same, but i am not geting the output
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
RoleCheckBox.Parent.Controls.Remove(RoleCheckBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a proper reference to your checkboxes - mRoleCheckBoxList is not mentioned as part of your checkbox creation.

Try the following in your button event handler:

```
foreach (TableRow row in Table1.Rows)
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {

        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];
        if (check.Checked) check.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Always when creating dynamic controls in .Net create them here:
     protected override void CreateChildControls()
     {

```
     base.CreateChildControls();
     this.CreateDynamicControls();

 } //eof method
```

and in the PostBack find the them either from the event trigger or from a non-dynamic control:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Search for a control within the passed root control by the control id passed as string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="root">the upper control to start to search for</param>
    /// <param name="id">the id of the control as string</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual Control FindControlRecursively(Control root, string id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (root.ID == id)
            {
                return root;
            } //eof if

            foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
            {
                Control t = this.FindControlRecursively( c, id);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    return t;
                } //eof if
            } //eof foreach
        } //eof try 
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return null;
        } //eof catch

        return null;
    } //eof method
```